# Ubuntu VM not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have downloded Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop ISO image.  I have followed all the steps given in the link http://www.securitybeacon.com/?p=578 .However I am not able to see Ubuntu Desktop . I have waited for 2 hrs still not able to see any progress. I tried re-installing the VM but it didn't work.Please find attached image. Please guide.

Comment: What does it display? Which error does it report? And don't use Ubuntu 12.04. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has been released long ago

Comment: Yes I tried 14.04 initially but it didn't work.It displays message "Write same failed. Manually Zeroing", but still I am able to login to ubuntu machine but not able to see graphical environment .

Comment: Try installing it manually. Don't use easy install

Comment: Could you please post the whole error message/ kernel logs?

Comment: I am not able to see GUI , It displays shell screen with "ubuntu login: option" It doesn't display any error.